# break-word (not break-all) in container with floating child in Firefox

Tags: css, overflow, css-float

A text with `overflow-wrap: break-word` side by side with a `float` element works nicely in Chrome but Firefox doesn't word break as expected, it doesn't take the floating element's width into account.

**Screenshot from chrome (this is the desired output)**

The long word 'Antiestablishmentarianism' is broken since it can't fit the available space - other words that do fit remain intact.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

**Screenshot from the failed rendering in Firefox**

The long word isn't broken as expected, instead it's pushed down below the yellow floating element.  Some word-breaking is going on -  as the last letter `m` ends up on a separate row. Seems like Firefox can't quite handle word-wrap + the yellow floating element.

[image: FF screenshot]

**So the question is:** Is there any way to make Firefox render the word-break as nicely as Chrome without removing the `float` element? (I know, I could probably add more HTML wrappers and use flex or something instead - but I'd prefer to keep the current structure)

```css
section {
  width: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.yellow-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
   
<section>
  <span class="yellow-box"></span>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Gotta say Antiestablishmentarianism is quite a long word indeed
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

**PS:** I don't wanna use `break-all` because it'll break more words than necessary

But the interesting thing is that if you use `word-break: break-all;` in Firefox it works perfectly and the floating element's width IS taken into consideration

**Screenshot using `break-all`**

As you can see the word 'indeed' is also broken, which is not OK

[image: word-break: break-all in FF]

*All screenshots in this post were taken using Chrome 114 and FF 114*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `.yellow-box` is floating, you have to reset the BFC of h1 so it doesn't lay under the floating box. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

```css
section {
  width: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
}

section h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  overflow:hidden; /* BFC */
}

.yellow-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span class="yellow-box"></span>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Gotta say Antiestablishmentarianism is quite a long word indeed
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use grid instead, this way you can keep the same structure of HTML and just change the CSS.

```css
section {
  width: 400px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 100px;
}
section div {
    align-self: start;
    background: lightblue;
}
section h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 0;
}

.yellow-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row: 1/2
}
```

```html
<section>
    <span class="yellow-box"></span>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Gotta say Antiestablishmentarianism is quite a long word indeed
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Using the `grid-column-start` property on the `yellow-box` allows you to move it to the second column without changing it's position in the HTML. Then you just need to make sure it stays in the first row with `grid-row: 1/2`. You'll also need to make it so that only the div is getting the lightblue background but that's simple to change.